# Illegal byte sequence zipro W 10-02 23:01:47 10808 9104 Error opening archive T:\my_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: I/O error ERROR: dump

Tags: flutter, build, compiler-errors, android-manifest

I have created this project before and I'm trying to run it again but I am getting the following error(s) :

Error Log:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
ziparchive W 10-02 23:01:47 10808  9104 Unable to open 'T:my_ap\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk': Illegal byte sequence
zipro W 10-02 23:01:47 10808  9104 Error opening archive T:\my_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: I/O error
ERROR: dump failed because resource AndroidManifest.xml not found
Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: The command failed
  Command: C:\Users\cordt\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3\aapt dump xmltree T:\batí\Mail\projects\shop_app_3\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml.
Exception: Problem building Android application: see above error(s).
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have tried `flutter clean` but it didn't help me.

Comment: I've the same problem right now!.

Comment: Did you try "flutter create ."

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem on an app I've been working on, the key takeaway is that this happened immediately after I update to the latest version of My flutter SDK. These are the steps I followed to solve this problem.

- flutter create .
- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- flutter run